# Conditionally remove duplicates duplicated rows in spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to achieve the following thing:

```
val df1 = Seq(("a","x",20),("z","x",10),("b","y",7),("z","y",5),("c","w",1),("z","w",2)).toDS


+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  x| 20|
|  z|  x| 10|
|  b|  y|  7|
|  z|  y|  5|
|  c|  w|  1|
|  z|  w|  2|
+---+---+---+
```

should be reduced to

```
val df2 = Seq(("a","x",30),("b","y",12),("c","w",3)).toDS

+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  a|  x| 30|
|  b|  y| 12|
|  c|  w|  3|
+---+---+---+
```

I am aware of the `dropDuplicates()`command with its options. But for what I ould like to achieve this does not work. Somehow one has to detect the duplicates according to column `_2` and then one has to remove the always the row with the `z` entry in `_1` and add its `_3` value to the the `_3`column that one keeps.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I get it correct, this hardly can be achieved in Spark, because it does NOT guarantee that order will be preserved on your dataset, so it can be in order a, b, c, z, z, z of _1 field. So it's not clear, value of which row that has 'z' in field _1 have to be added to row with 'a' for example. So, it makes sense to solve this with plain Scala/Python/etc code. It should not consume a lot of memory even for large dataset since you can use iterator - you need only 2 rows at once to produce output

Answer (score 0):

As per your question this is what you are looking for

```
import spark.implicits._
val df1 = Seq(("a","x",20),("z","x",10),("b","y",7),("z","y",5),("c","w",1),("z","w",2)).toDS

val resultDf = df1.groupBy("_2").agg(collect_list("_1")(0).as("_1"), sum("_3").as("_3"))
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+
| _2| _1| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  x|  a| 30|
|  w|  c|  3|
|  y|  b| 12|
+---+---+---+
```

You will get the result but the order is not guaranteed.

Comment: I just dont quite understand the `collect_list` command. But otherwise, it is what I want, since the order of how the rows are arranged doesnt matter to me. I could still order them if it would.

Comment: collect_list collects all the that are grouped by in a array such as (a,z) for x group and (b,z) for y and so on and after that take only the first element.

Comment: Allright. Then it does not work the way it should, because order in that sense matters. If I change the row order to `|c | w|1|` comes after `| z|  w|  2|`, the result should stay the same as in the question. - I cant accept the answer yet, since it does no solve the problem :)

Comment: that can be done but how do you know which to take ? take after sorting ?

Comment: Always the `z` value should be deleted. I should not have taken letters as example it is confusing I guess. The `z` is just a placeholder for a `String` that is always the same, whereas `a`,`b` and `c` are different `Strings`, but one can not order them according alphabetically

Comment: that means you can filter the values like z from the list

Comment: all `z`that have no duplicates in `_2`can be filtered away.
E.g. if I add the entry `| z| q| 2|` it should appear unchanged in the result table, because it has no duplicate

Comment: This is getting more complex and complex :)

Comment: You can filter according to the size wont that work ?

Comment: I tried to show the complexity in a minimal example, but appearently a bit too minimal :) no that doesnt work. I just thought about somehow  subtract the duplicated entries from the original table and do somhow a join combined with a summation..but there is still the problem with the order I suppose

Comment: I think the better option would be goupby collect as a list and apply an udf to get the result

Comment: This exceeds my horizon/knowledge, I would be super thankful if you could give me a hint/solution :)

Comment: absolutely no clue what you mean :/

Comment: can you provide me the full logic so that i could implement ?

Comment: What more do you need? - shoud I rewrite the question?
I will try to give more info if needed tomorrow